# Is it possible to share a Shortcut Automation with others?

Tags: iphone, automation, shortcuts-app

I'm just starting to play with iPhone Shortcut Automations. They are really cool for *personal productivity* projects. But what about deploying to a team, department or entire org (whom all use iPhones)?

Is it possible to share a Shortcut **Automation**? Maybe export it, save it under version control and have others within the team/dept/org download it and use it?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/guide/shortcuts/apdf01f8c054/ios

Comment: Thank you for the link. I edited the OP to callout Shortcut **Automations**. I actually don't have any "Shortcuts" showing in "My Shortcuts", only Automations. I want to know if its possible to share them.

Comment: Don‘t see a way to do this currently (unless you use screenshots).

Comment: Yeah...I'm trying to write "How to..." instructions for an Automation that I want to share. Its brutal because of all the little nuances. "Step 4190: Click the little arrow to change xyz"! Would be DRASTICALLY easier to click the "Share" button!

Answer (score 3):

Would it work if you create Shortcut Automation as a "normal" Shortcut (which apple [explains](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/share-shortcuts-apdf01f8c054/ios) how to share as @Lano already pointed out)

Then in Shortcut Automation you create an Automation that uses the Run Shortcut command to run the shared shortcut.

Your team still has to manually setup the Shortcut Automation, but does not have to "program" the entire Shortcut.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Personal automations are not shareable. Non-automated, or regular Shortcuts are.

Like the previous responder explained, it can be done if you create your personal automations differently. And with automations consisting out of 4 steps or more, you should consider always doing this, really..

A personal automation made in Shortcuts consists out of two parts.

1)The easy first part: “when X occurs”, or something similar.

2)The second, mostly more complicated part where you “write” the automation “code” to make your device perform the given tasks, is actually shareable -when you create it in the correct part of the Shortcuts app-.

Here’s how:

Instead of writing this “code” within the actual automation, you should write this “code” in a regular, non-automated Shortcut, and then let the automation you’re creating run that regular Shortcut.

This Shortcut is not only shareable, but it syncs with iCloud, making it available to all your supporting devices immediately.